# How do I search for file extension and content in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, search

In Windows XP this was very simple, but for some reason in Windows 7 it is not...

I want to search for all files from C given an extension "example: *.sql" that contains the content "table_abc".

I searched and the only information I got was to change *Tools* → *Folder options* → *Search* → *"always search file names and contents..."*, but this is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the search bar on the upper right hand corner of the file explorer you need to add the prefix `type:` and `content:`.

So the search you would perform is "`content:table_abc type:.sql`" *without quotes*

Here is an image for reference. In it I searched for a .sql file containing the word "object_data". The search I performed was `type:.sql content:object_data`

---

[image: Search]

Comment: Doesn't work to me. For example, I have `toml` files, some of them contain `version` word, so I use `file:.toml content:version`, and get "No items match your search"

Answer (score 2):

In windows 2012 Search the syntax would be:

```
file:.sln Project1.proj
```

or

```
file:.ext content:"My Content String"
```

2012 does not recognize *type*, but does recognize *file* and content is optional.

This is a good way to find Solutions in a source tree is you know a filename.